# How to edit CellTemplate in Expression Blend 4

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, expression-blend

Here's a thing that I don't understand about editing cell templates in Expression Blend 4:

When I create cell template manually through xaml, the code looks like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:leartWPF" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="leartWPF.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window1"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:GroupDataSource x:Key="GroupDataSourceDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupDataSourceDataSource}}">
        <DataGrid  Margin="0" HeadersVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupExtednenDatas, ElementName=Window}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Groups" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="200"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>     
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Which results in a window, which looks more or less alright:

[image]

When I try to do the same using Expression Blend's menu,

[image]

I end up with following code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:leartWPF" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="leartWPF.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window1"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:GroupDataSource x:Key="GroupDataSourceDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="200"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupDataSourceDataSource}}">
        <DataGrid  Margin="0" HeadersVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupExtednenDatas, ElementName=Window}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Groups" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate}" >

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>     
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

which displays empty cells no matter what I put inside the

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate"> :
```

[image]

Do I do anything wrong, or is this Expression Blend bug? And if this is a bug, how should I change the XAML code to fix it?

Comment: As far as I can see they only differ in how the template is declared: inline the former, in a resource the latter. Are you sure you are using the same code-behind? P.s. Is the typo wanted in `DataGrid` ItemsSource?

Comment: I actually redid that several times. Also, I just replaced the DynamicResource with StaticResource, and it works again. There seems to be a problem related specifically to DynamicResource's here

Answer (score 0):

I might be totally off base, if so, sorry for not understanding, but it seems the question is over-complicating what's needed. CellTemplate is just a placeholder for anything - in the data grid it's empty by default, so you can put whatever you want in it -> in your case it's a placeholder for a TextBlock. That's what you would need to edit in Blend, or whatever other control you are putting in the CellTemplate.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to referencing a template with DynamicResource not working. The problem works correctly with the link as StaticResource.